# Javascript - how do I iterate thru all URLs of a given page

Tags: javascript

I am not experienced in Javascript. After the page finishes loading, I need to iterate thru all URLs a given page and perform some cleanings.

How do I do that?

Something like

```
for i = 0 to (number of URLS on the page) {

  doSomething (URL(i));

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to link through all anchors, use [`document.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.links), like this:

```
for(var i = 0, l=document.links.length; i<l; i++) {
  doSomething(document.links[i].href);
}
```

This is a collection already maintained by the browser (for prefetching under the covers mostly, but other reasons as well)...no need for a `document.getElementsByTagName()` here. Note: this also gets `<area>` elements, as long as they have a `href` attribute...also a valid form of navigation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd always recommend having [jQuery](http://jquery.com) around for times like this as it makes it far easier.

For example on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(index) {
        alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: jQuery is *tremendous* overkill for this...this is completely built-in, why include a library just for this?

Comment: Because very few websites have only this and if they do they normally expand to include other functionality. Having a library like jQuery (which is lightweight) makes for an easier experience and one that's comfortable to grow with.

Comment: I agree *if* you're using jQuery take advantage of it (though it's still tremendously less efficient here), but in this situation it just makes zero sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (anchor in anchors){ 
  doSomething(anchor):
}
```

Comment: Why run a selector for a built-in collection?  Also do **not** use a `for..in` loop to *iterate* over a collection, it's for *enumeration*, which can produce undesired results here.

Answer (score 0):

Or just plain Javascript with a bit of readability:

```
var myURL = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0; i<myURL.length; i++)
    console.log(myURL[i].getAttribute('href'));
```